# aws_wafv2_rule_group Rate based rule

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, amazon-waf

I am struggling to create a rate based wafv2 rule group; i am getting below error when doing  a plan.
not sure is this feature available in terraform till now. below is my code and error:
I have also upgrade terraform and provider registry:

Terraform v1.0.9; on windows_amd64; provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.63.0

**terraform code:**

```
  name     = "test-rulegroup-ratelimit"
  scope    = "REGIONAL"
  capacity = 5

  rule {
    name     = "test-rulegroup-ratelimit"
    priority = 1

    action {
      count {}
    }

    statement {
      rate_based_statement {
        limit              = 9999
        aggregate_key_type = "IP"
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
      metric_name                = "test-rulegroup-ratelimit"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    metric_name                = "test-rulegroup-ratelimit"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
│
│   on r_rulegroup.tf line 15, in resource "aws_wafv2_rule_group" "test-rulegroup-ratelimit":
│   15:       rate_based_statement {
│
│ Blocks of type "rate_based_statement" are not expected here.""
```

I cannot find anything specific for wafv2 just like classic waf:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/waf_rate_based_rule

Comment: For some strange reason it seems it's only possible to create rate based rules when you're declaring the WAFv2 itself. The AWS API supports creating rate limit rules in rule sets, but TF doesn't AFAICS

Comment: See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20908